# Receiving an error and stuck with debugging

Tags: magento-1.7, php, error, debugging

I am kinda stuck with this issue here. I am getting this error code in PHP:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getUsedProducts() in line 23...
```

Since I am kinda new to Magento I am wondering if somehow this code snippet I got might be wrong or so. Maybe you guys could take a look and let me know if it all seems right. I can't even **`var_dump`** the **`$_products`** variable.

Here is the code snippet: https://ghostbin.com/paste/n9t23

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check that product is configurable or child so you should change code like below

```
public function getStockInfo($_product)
{
    var_dump($_product);
    if($_product->isConfigurable())
    {
        $stockVariants = array();
        $usedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)-     >getUsedProducts(null, $_product);

        foreach ($usedProducts as $simple) 
        {
            $stock =(int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple)->getQty();
            if ($stock >= 3) {
                $stock = 3;
            }
            $stockVariants[$simple->getSize()] = $stock;
        }

        return $stockVariants;
    }

}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are getting the child products from a simple product.

You need to add the following condition before declaring the `$usedProducts` variable:

```
if ($_product->getTypeId == "configurable")
```